# Making two boxes equal each other

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a text box (`UPC_txtBox4`) self populate to equal the same value of `UPC_txtBox2`. The two text boxes are on separate forms but I feel there should be a way to link the two.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you need to "link" them? Do changes to one affect the other? Vice versa?

Comment: show code which populate first textbox, and code which creates both forms

Comment: what type of app are talking about? winforms, wpf, web forms...?

Comment: the first text box is not auto populated it is user input.

Comment: by link I mean I need to have user input in several text boxes such as a upc code then click "Place Order" on the first form and go to the next form and have a text box on the second form that is also upc code that has the info input on the first form automatically there.

Comment: frennky it is a web form application in Visual Studios 2010

Answer (score 1):

If form1 is responsible for navigating to form2, then you can pass the value on the query string from form1 using a URL similar to the following:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.ApplicationPath + "/Form2.aspx?upc=" + UPC_txtBox2.Text, false);
        }
    }
```

then in form2 code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Assuming this field is an asp.net textbox and not an HTML input
            UPC_txtBox4.Text = Request.QueryString["upc"];
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could store the value in session state, assuming that you are using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

**CORRECTION: Seeing as you are using WebForms, not WinForms as I had assumed, the below is irrelevant.  I'll leave it just incase it helps someone else.**

You should just create a method on the form that needs to be updated, then pass a reference when of that form to the newly created form.

This won't work if either form is a dialog (as far as I know).

So:

Form that has the textbox that will be directly edited.

```
private Form formToUpdate;
public void OpenForm(Form _formToUpdate)
{
    formToUpdate = _formToUpdate;
    txtBlah.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnTextChanged);
    this.Show();
}

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   formToUpdate.UpdateText(txtBlah.Text);
}
```

Form that is to be dynamically updated:

```
delegate void StringParameterDelegate (string value);
public void UpdateText(string textToUpdate)
{
     if (InvokeRequired)
     {
        BeginInvoke(new StringParameterDelegate(UpdateText), new object[]{textToUpdate});
        return;
     }
     // Must be on the UI thread if we've got this far
     txtblah2.Text = textToUpdate;
 }
```

Note: this is untested (although it should work), and largely pseudo code, you'll need to tailor it to your solution obviously.